# is it a good practice to create Independent tests?

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests

I have read in multiple blogs that we should keep our automation tests independent, for example: https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/5-reasons-why-test-automation-can-fail
What I mean by independent is that each test should create and cleanup its own data and not rely on tests in other groups to create data.
Then in which scenarios should we use the dependsOnGroups annotation from TestNG, considering that the tests in the group could be spread across multiple classes and they will no longer be independent.

Comment: What do you mean by "independent" here? If you mean independent in the sense that individual tests give exactly the same result if only a subset of the overall test suite is run; or if they are run in a different order, then yes: this is clearly a good thing.

Comment: Independent means each test creating and cleaning its own data, and not relying on other tests in other groups for data to be created. And yes, what you said is also true. If the tests are responsible for their own data, their execution result will be the same regardless of if they run as a subset or in some different order.

Comment: We create suites. 

a. Its too much trouble for every test to be independent.
b. Some scenarios are not tested if indepedant or have too many steps. its better to model the real world. have a  suite.its saved us  a few times

Comment: Okay. so lets say we create the data in a method in class A, assign this method to a group testGroup and then in class B, for every test, we write dependsOnGroups(testGroup) ? Class A and Class B are part of the same suite.